# What is the equivalent in CSS of the SASS/SCSS expression "&$"?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

Hello I am trying to understand how a material-ui component works, and I come across the following styling:

```
root: (0, _extends3.default)({}, theme.typography.subheading, {  
  height: theme.spacing.unit * 3,  
  boxSizing: 'content-box',  
  overflow: 'hidden',  
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',  
  whiteSpace: 'nowrap',  
  '&:hover': {  
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.text.lightDivider  
  },  
  '&$selected': {  
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.text.divider  
  }  
 }),  
 selected: {}  
}
```

I want to know what the '&$selected' would mean in CSS syntax.
The issue I come across is that I want to overwrite the background-color passing the styling through to selected, but it is not overwriting it. I want to understand what is happening behind the scenes here. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: `$selected` is the name of a variable in your code and will compile to whatever is contained in that variable.  It is not standard CSS.

Comment: `&$` is not a thing but `&$selected` will be the combination of the parent selector (`&`) and the value of the `$selected` variable.  If we're being literal, this is not CSS syntax but SCSS or SASS syntax.

Comment: I understand it is not CSS, my question is what does this compile to in CSS! What would the equivalent of the expression '&$selected' be in CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent for the expression `&$selected` in css. `&$` Is not a special symbol in both of the languages.
`&$selected` in scss combine from 2 parts:

1. `&`: sccc- right after the parent selector insert new sub-selectors. eample:

**scss:**

```
main-selector {
    color: blue;

    &.sub-selector {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**equivalent css:**

```
main-selector {
    color: blue;
}
main-selector.sub-selector {
    display: block;
}
```

As you can see, the `&` symbol doesn't exist at all in css, and only apears in scss code.

2. `$selected` - this means a variable in scss. In the css code you will not be able to know if there was using in variables in the source scss file.
   this variable can represent every thing in css- including selectors' names, specific colors, arrays of values, indexes, counter etc.
   I can't tell you what does this variable represent in your code according to the code that you published, even that I know that it is in use, the only thing that I know about it's value in your case, is that it include a selector (And I don't know which one).

It is important you to understand, that most of the new symbols in scss, created to save lines of css code (and I think you do). But to know exactly the final compilation to css from scss code, you need to publish the whole scss code, including the files import from the scss file itself.

I hope I made it more clearly now.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clearer. From what I understood, somewhere in the code the $selected is being declared, but it is unrelated to the selected defined in the code I shared. I need to look again at the source of the component to see if I missed the other selected. Thanks!